# passing parameters to web method

Tags: c#, objective-c, xmlhttprequest, webmethod

On a web server is the following method:

```
[WebMethod()]
public static string login(string userName, string password)
{
    if (usernName == "test" && password == "test")
    {
         return "validated";
    }
    return "error";
}
```

I'm trying to connect to it with the following Objective C code:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"userName="test"&password="test"];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSString *serverURLString = @"http://myURL.aspx/login";
NSURL *serverURL = [NSURL URLWithString:serverURLString];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:serverURL];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request addValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];

NSLog(@"response data = %@", responseData);
```

I got lost in ignorant newbie land and thought the last line would print out either "validated" or "error" in my Objective C console but it returns an integer (which I'm sure is obvious to those of you who have done this before =)).

Can anyone tell me how I would get to see the webMethod return value in my Objective C log?

-EDIT-
I've just noticed that I get an HTTP response status code of 200, regardless of whether I use the correct userName/password combination or not, which I'm guessing could also mean the issue lies elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `NSString` using the `NSData` returned in the response. E.g.:

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Thanks Ian. Should this string contain the webMethod return value? It seems to only return the HTML for the page (although I guess this could mean my error is in the actual connection).

Comment: Yes, in theory you should see "validated" or "error" printed. The fact you are getting HTML often means you're getting an error on the server side returned.

Comment: I'm sure it's just a copy/paste issue or something, but your string for the post parameters needs editing: NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"userName=\"test\"&password=\"test\""];

Comment: Thanks again Ian. I seem to be having an issue somewhere else so I'll accept close this one and post a simplified question.